# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{\ln(x^2+1)dx}{x}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am interested in finding an exact expression for the integral
$$\int \frac{\ln(x^2+1)dx}{x}$$
I start by using the transformation $w=\ln(x^2+1)$ leading to $e^{w}dw=2xdx$. Unfortunately, I couldn't get rid of $x$ in there: $$\int \frac{we^w}{2x^2}dw$$ and I'm not interested in results with an infinite series.

I would like to know a suitable substitution that may involve only one variable leading to an expression less complicated for integration. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is $$-\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(-x^2\right)}{2}$$

Comment: yes this is what wolfram is showing...can you explain what Li is?

Comment: Thanks. However, this kind of expression is what I want to avoid. Thus, I need alternate expression.

Comment: @MarvelMaharrnab This special function is called [*Dilogarithm*, or *Spence's Function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function).

Comment: @MarvelMaharrnab, sure this is what I got when I tried it on wolfram. And this  $L_{i_n}(y)$ is defined as a polylog function $L_{i_n}(y)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^m}{m^n}$, for $n=1,2,\dots$. This is what I am avoiding because it would add extra difficulty to implement to plot numerically.

Comment: @M.D.: some integrals cannot be expressed in elementary functions, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)

Comment: @M.D. Sadly speaking there is no other alternative way of representing the anti-derivative of this function. You could check whether the final expression can be simplified using Dilogarithm identities; but a expression avoiding Polylogarithms completely...this isn't possible.

Comment: wow...i didnt knew these stuff....thank you...will surely try to learn more about it

Comment: Is there anything that might be improvable which prevents you from accepting one of the given answers?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible by using elementary functions yet alone. The [Dilogarithm, or Spence's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) is capable of providing an anti-derivative. Note that the aforementioned function my defined as integral

> $$\operatorname{Li}_2(x):=-\int\frac{\log(1-x)}x\mathrm dx$$

Enforcing the substitution $x^2=-t$ within your given integral gives us

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\log(1+x^2)}x\mathrm dx&=\int\frac{\log(1+x^2)}x\frac{2x}{2x}\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac12\int\frac{\log(1-t)}t\mathrm dt\\
&=-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(t)\\
&=-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)
\end{align*}

> $$\therefore~\int\frac{\log(1+x^2)}x\mathrm dx~=~-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(-x^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

To remove the ugly "$-x^2$".

\begin{align}F(x)&=\int_0^x \frac{\ln(t^2+1)dt}{t}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x \frac{2t\ln(t^2+1)dt}{t^2}\,dt\\
\end{align}
Perform the change of variable $y=t^2$,
\begin{align}F(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{x^2}\dfrac{\ln(1+t)}{t}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\ln t\ln(1+t)\Big]_0^{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{x^2} \frac{\ln t}{1+t}\,dt\\
&=\ln x\ln(1+x^2)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{x^2} \frac{\ln t}{1+t}\,dt\\
&=\ln x\ln(1+x^2)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{x^2}\dfrac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt+\int_0^{x^2}\frac{t\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt\\
\end{align}
In the last integral perform the change of variable $y=t^2$,
\begin{align}F(x)&=\ln x\ln(1+x^2)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{x^2}\dfrac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{x^4}\dfrac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt\end{align}

In the first integral perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{t}{x^2}$,

In the second integral perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{t}{x^4}$,

\begin{align}F(x)&=\ln x\ln(1+x^2)-\frac{x^2}{2}\int_0^{1}\dfrac{\ln(tx^2)}{1-tx^2}\,dt+\frac{x^4}{4}\int_0^{1}\dfrac{\ln(tx^4)}{1-tx^4}\,dt\\
&=\ln x\ln(1+x^2)-x^2\ln x\int_0^{1}\dfrac{1}{1-tx^2}\,dt+x^4\ln x\int_0^{1}\dfrac{1}{1-tx^4}\,dt-\\
&\frac{x^2}{2}\int_0^{1}\dfrac{\ln t}{1-tx^2}\,dt+\frac{x^4}{4}\int_0^{1}\dfrac{\ln t}{1-tx^4}\,dt\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\text{Li}_2(x^2)-\frac{1}{4}\text{Li}_2(x^4)}
\end{align}

NB:

For $0\leq x<1$, $\text{Li}_2$ is defined by,
\begin{align}\text{Li}_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n^2}\end{align}

For $0<x<1$, 
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln t}{1-tx}\,dt=\dfrac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{x}\end{align}

Proof:
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln t}{1-tx}\,dt&=\int_0^1 \left(\ln t\sum_{n=0}^\infty (tx)^n\right)\,dt\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\int_0^1 t^n\ln t\,dt\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=-\dfrac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{x}
\end{align}

Because, for $n\geq 0$, integer
\begin{align}\int_0^1 t^n\ln t\,dt=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use the taylor series centred around $a=1$ to find a series for this integral.
$$I=\int\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{x}dx=\frac12\int\frac{\ln(u)}{u-1}du$$
and we can say that:
$$f(u)=\ln(u)$$
and by following the pattern of differentiating this function:
$$f(u)=\ln(u)$$
$$f'(u)=0!(-1)^1x^{-1}$$
$$f''(u)=1!(-1)^2x^{-2}$$
etc. so we can say that:
$$\frac{d^nf(u)}{du}=(n-1)!(-1)^{n-1}u^{-n}$$
and if $u=1$ then this $u$ term will disappear, giving:
$$\ln(u)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(u-1)^n(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$
and so we can say that:
$$I=\frac12\int\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(u-1)^{n-1}}{n}du$$
$$I=\frac12\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(u-1)^n}{n+1}du$$
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(u-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}+C$$
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2(n+1)}}{(n+1)^2}+C$$